# Bayesian fixed effects model and invariant variables

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, fixed-effects-model

Within a fixed effects approach, the effects of invariant variables cannot be estimated. Their effects are captured by the fixed effects.
However, when I estimate following Bayesian fixed effects model in R

`bayesglm(y ~ variant variables + invariant variables + factor(identity variable 1), family = gaussian())`

by means of the function bayesglm, I get estimates for the invariant variables, too.

I am not familiar with Bayesian approaches, hence my question: Why is it possible to get these estimates in a Bayesian fixed effects model?

Thanks in advance,

Sören

Comment: Could you describe your model a little bit further? Have you checked if the "estimated" effects are not exactly the same as your prior distributions and/or do not have very large variances..? What R package do you use for estimation?

Comment: Hi Tim. I am using the R-package arm. The estimates for the fixed effects are identical with the estimates of a glm estimation. However, in the glm estimation I cannot estimate the effects for invariant variables. This I can only do with the Bayesian function bayesglm.

Comment: and my question was about the estimates of invariant variables

Comment: Please provide the general framework. If the question is solely about the R package, it should migrate to Stack Overflow.